# Insertion errors encountered for java.io.IOException

Tags: java, google-bigquery, apache-beam

I'm relatively new with Apache Beam Pipeline and am trying to modify an existing beam pipeline code by inserting a parameter in a 'Data' class and retrieving it to do further calculations in subsequent steps, as below.

```
public class Data {  
  @JsonProperty("loss")
  private double loss;

  public double getLoss() {
    return loss;
  }

  public void setLoss(double loss) {
    this.loss = loss;
  }
}
```

I've also made changes to the schema in data.json as below:

```
final TableSchema dataSchema = SchemaLoader.load("/data.json");

writeIntoBigQuery(options.getDataTableName(), dataSchema, Data, new InputToTableRow());
```

However, I'm still getting a runtime error (I only reproduced the first few lines, the rest seem to be complaining about more or less the same thing). Initially I thought it may be because my BigQuery table doesn't have a 'loss' field as part of the table schema and went to add it but its still happening.. Is there somewhere else in the code I should add or modify to make this error go away? Or anything else I should do to get more details on how to troubleshoot?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"generic::not_found: no such field.","location":"loss","message":"no such field.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(StreamingWriteFn.java:106)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(StreamingWriteFn.java:82)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"generic::not_found: no such field.","location":"loss","message":"no such field.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
```

Comment: Are you able to share your full pipeline code?

Comment: did you end up figuring this one out?

Comment: Its some time ago I can't remember exactly, but I think it was because I didn't create a "loss" column in Bigquery table. Hope this helps!